# Uploading expo application version to app store

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, application-loader

I have been uploading versions of my app for a while, and suddenly, after an update of mac os, I cannot upload my app anymore, I've upgraded my mac os version, xcode and  still nothing....

**UPDATE**

Its important to note that this is a react native application that i am generating using expo by running  `expo build ios`

these are the errors that i am getting...

> ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements
> in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained
> in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not
> included in the provisioning profile:
> 'com.apple.developer.icloud-services' in
> 'Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/ExpoKitApp'."
>
> WARNING ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the
> iOS 11.4 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App
> Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode
> 10.1 or later."

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The first part, ITMS-90163, is an error -- basically stating that your app is trying to use iCloud but the provisioning profile (that you set up  at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com)) doesn't have iCloud enabled.  This is what's blocking your upload.

Since you say this just started happening, **probably** this means the iCloud switch in Xcode got flipped on accidentally (if your app is not a actually using iCloud).

In **Xcode 10.1**, be sure your project is selected in the upper left and your target is selected, then click on the **Capabilities** tab and scroll down until you see **iCloud**, and click it **OFF**.  **Important:  This is only a reasonable choice if your app does not use iCloud.**

[image: Xcode 10.1 - Disable iCloud]

If your app does use iCloud, you instead need to generate a new provisioning profile.  You can do this manually by going to [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com), and click on **Account** in the upper right.  Click "**Certificates, IDs, & Profiles**", and follow [Apple's instructions](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devf2eb157f8).  However, you can have Xcode managing provisioning profiles for you *automatically*, by clicking on the **General** tab and then checking the box "**Automatically Manage Signing**".

[image: Xcode 10.1 - Automatically Manage Signing]

The second part, ITMS-90725, is just a warning, so it's not blocking you from uploading (though it will be a problem in March).  To resolve this, first, be sure you are on Xcode 10.1 or later.  (While in Xcode, go up to the menu bar and click Xcode -> About Xcode to check.). It's possible that you could be using Xcode 10.1 and still not using the latest SDK for some reason. Under **Build Settings**, check **Base SDK**.  It should just say "**iOS**".

[image: Xcode 10.1 -- Base SDK]

Comment: but this is not a regular objectC/Swift app, this is a react-native application that i generate the ipa and upload it directly through the application loader

Comment: It's been awhile since I worked with ReactNative, but I'm pretty sure it creates an Xcode project that you should be able to go in and edit and then build.  There might be some react settings too, but I don't know.